# Консольная строка в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

При работе с sass,если указать свойство...например("padding") и не указать ему значение(например,случайно перешел на другую строку).Вылезает консоль с ошибкой,но когда она вылезит,курсор со строк кода переходит на поиск файлов в проекте.Можно ли сделать задержку перед выводом ошибки в консоль или как ее отключить для sass?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, вы используете SASS file watcher... Вы можете выключить опцию **Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher** в его свойствах (**Settings | Tools | File Watchers**) - тогда компилятор будет запускаться только при явном сохранении (`Ctrl+S`) или переключении фокуса на другое приложение.

Описываемая вами проблема (фокус на *Project* tool window после закрытия консоли) похожа на [IDEA-187010](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187010), пожалуйста, проголосуйте за этот баг